Issues with LibreOffice Icons on Dark Mode in Linux Mint
I’m currently using Linux Mint 22 Cinnamon edition, version 6.2.7, which I reinstalled today on my laptop. When I open LibreOffice Writer, I’m experiencing an issue where some icons aren’t clearly visible in dark mode. The icons appear blurry or hard to see, but I haven’t tested it in light mode yet.
Here are some details about my current version:
LibreOffice Version: 24.2.5.2 (X86_64) / LibreOffice Community
Build ID: 420(Build:2)
OS Kernel: Linux 6.8
UI Renderer: Default (VCL: gtk3)
Locale: en-US (en_US.UTF-8)
Ubuntu package version: 4:24.2.5-0ubuntu0.24.04.2
Calc: Threaded


I’ve attached a screenshot to provide more clarity on the issue. Does anyone know how I can resolve this or what might be causing it? Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks in advance!
